# MySQL latin1 only for single PHP vhost

Tags: apache-2.4, encoding

I have no control over the PHP application, but I have on Apache.

I know how to set `php_value` for a particular vhost. I need to tell that vhost to use `latin1` character set when connecting to MySQL instead of the system's default `utf8`. Other vhosts **must** not be affected.

Any ideas? From what I can read that shouldn't be possible via php.ini.
While I have the option of running a custom PHP script for every request (with `auto_prepend_file`) I must have already opened a MySQL connection.

Comment: simply setting the [default collation and character set](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-database.html) on the database side is not sufficient?

Comment: I haven't tried collate yet